# Can there be a function whose domain is larger than codomain but all elements of domain is not used?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Greetings fellow mathematicians! I'm curious about the problem and thought your insights may help.

Let $S =\{ \sqrt{p/q} : p,q \in \mathbb{N}, \ \mathrm{gcd}(p,q)=1\}$

Define $f:Q \to S$ such that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$.

I'm curious if the relation is a function and if so then is it one-one and onto?

My intuition tells me that all the elements of $Q$ are rational numbers but $S$ contains irrational numbers. I know the set of rational is countable whereas the set of irrational is uncountable. I've also observed that $S$ will not contain all the irrational numbers but will contain many for sure.

Please do share your insights and please let me know how to verify.

Comment: $S$ is a countable subset of the irrational numbers.  So, yes, this is a bijection, and the domain and co-domain have the same cardinality.

Comment: I do have one problem. $S$ may have rational numbers as well. Take p=4, q=1, $gcd(p,q)$=1 & \sqrt{4} = 2 \in $S$. How can I confirm that the set $S$ is countable?

Comment: Right, so, I should have said that $S$ is a countable subset of the real numbers.   The set of ordered pairs of integers $(p,q)$ is a countable set.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable insight.

Comment: The question in the body seems unrelated to the question in the title. Moreover, if "all the elements in the domain are not used", then you don't have a function.